# getting error when i added CHCSVPARSER

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, csv, ios6

From this link [CHCSVParser](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser), I followed step by step method and I get 1 error

```
/CHCSVParser.h Semantic Issue- Property attributes 'assign' and 'weak' are mutually exclusive
```

I have been trying to implement this from 5 days now.I have tried many methods but still unable to resolve this error. Please guide me to resolve this. I am a noob in iOS.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would suggest simply removing the `__weak` designator for the `parserDelegate` definition in `CHCSVParser.h`. This is non-ARC code, anyway, so `assign` is good enough.

By the way, are you using this in an ARC project? If so, you'll have to tell your project that these files are not employing Automatic Reference Counting using the [`-fno-objc-arc`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW15) flag:

[image: Turn off ARC for CHCSV code]

Comment: You are awesome!! Thanks that did it.I have another addon query How do I get only first line which are fields in this case separately so I can transfer it to bar graph.Sorry again for additional query .But that would help me so much more.Thanks Again for Everything.

Comment: @JacobWood I don't know what your CSV looks like, but if you have a line that looks like `NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];` then you can get the first "line" via `[array objectAtIndex:0]`. Obviously replace `0` with whatever number to get the appropriate row of data.

Comment: Thanks again Rob. 1Q. How do I insert data below each field in sqlite or representing on Bar Graph.    2Q. Please also suggest me any chart/graph .Thanks .Will really appreciate the help.Thanks.

Comment: @JacobWood To learn how to insert data into sqlite, search on Stack Overflow for "[ios] sqlite tutorial". Even better than doing sqlite manually would be [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) (the preferred iOS framework for persistent storage) or [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) (an excellent wrapper for SQLite that tremendously simplifies SQLite programming).

Comment: Thanks Rob for everything.This is great.If you have used any charting tools which you would recommend .I tried core plot,fusion charts but I dont know which is good.Thanks Rob again.

Comment: @JacobWood On charting tools, I'd again suggest you again search on Stack Overflow, this time for "[ios] charting". You'll see tons of good answers out there. I've never done a comparison of the various libraries out there, so I'm not qualified to offer an opinion. But there are tons of opinions already out there on Stack Overflow!